# Game image recognition (Recognising Point Scored or Game over in Flappy Bird)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, reinforcement-learning

To familiarize myself with reinforcement learning, I am implementing the basic RL algorithm to play the game [Flappy Bird](https://github.com/sourabhv/FlapPyBird). I have everything set up, the only problem I am having is with implementing the reward function. I want to be able to process the screen and recognize whether a point has been scored or the bird has died.

Processing the screen is done using [mss](https://pypi.org/project/mss/#description) and opencv, which returns a [stacked numpy array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html). The reward function then needs to assign a reward to the provided array, but I have no idea how to go about this.

This is how a single processed image looks like:

[image: This is how a processed image looks like]

The idea I had for implementing the reward function was that if the background stops moving, the bird has died. And that if the bird is in a gap inbetween two pipes, the agent has scored a point. Any ideas in how can I express this in the numpy calculations ?

```
def _calculate_reward(self, state):
    """"
    calculate the reward of the state. Flappy is dead when the screen has stopped moving, so when two consecutive frames
    are equal. A point is scored when an obstacle is above flappy, and before it wasn't. An object is above Flappy when
    there are two white pixels in the first 50 pixels on the first row.

    :param state: np.array shape = (1, height, width, 4) - > four consecutive processed frames
    :return reward: int representing the reward if a point is scored or if flappy has died.
    """
    if np.sum((state[0,:,:,3] - state[0,:,:,2])) == 0 and np.sum((state[0,:,:,2] - state[0,:,:,1])) == 0:
        print("flappy is dead")
        return -1000
    elif sum(state[0,0,:50,3]) == 510 and sum(state[0,0,:50,2]) == 510 and sum(state[0,0,:50,1]) != 510 and sum(state[0,0,:50,0]) != 510:
        print("point!")
        return 1000
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using OpenCV how about trying [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) ?

[image: detecting mario coins using opencv python template matching]

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a push in the right direction!